# TemporaryStreamWrapper error during installation

Tags: 7, installation

In continuation to my previous question https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/208245/openatrium-installation-profile-error

I have another problem in the very next step i.e. during Site Configuration.

- Firstly the theme seems to have broken because CSS is not being applied.
- Secondly, I'm getting the error message.

  "Warning: file_put_contents(temporary://fil3BF3.tmp): failed to open stream: "DrupalTemporaryStreamWrapper::stream_open" call failed in file_unmanaged_save_data() (line 1936 of \includes\file.inc).

  •The file could not be created."

I understand from some other posts that this is due to missing permissions on "**sites/default/files**" folder. But this folder is created on the fly during installation how do we give access to it.
In addition, I believe another possible cause can be due to permissions to "**tmp**" folder. Most of the other posts mention changing that path in "Admin -> configuration" somewhere, but for that OpenAtrium needs to be completely installed. Where can I change the path for "**tmp**" file through file system.

Appreciate a reply.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Where can I change the path for "tmp" file through file system.

You can set the ***tmp*** path by appending the following line in the site ***settings.php***

```php
$conf['file_temporary_path'] = '/tmp';
```

In Addition, all item stored in **variable** table in Drupal site's database can be set with `$conf` array in the same way.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, is this path relative to settings.php ?

Comment: It's relative to the root directory of Drupal.